# Changing the brightness stopped working in 13.10 Saucy Salamander

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, brightness, 13.10

After the upgrade to 13.10 Saucy Salamander, the brightness controls stopped working. This worked fine from 12.04 throughout.

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this? If not, can you point me at the right package to file a bug against?

---

**Bug I filed so far**:
*https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1241745*

**Solutions I have tried:**

`/etc/default/grub`

Changed this line to several options:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` →

1. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`
2. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"`
3. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”acpi_osi="!Windows 2012"`

`sudo update-grub`

*None worked.*

I also tried to use `xbacklight`, which didn't work either. `xbacklight -get` wouldn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Timo Aaltonen (tjaalton) brought to my attention on IRC, this is bug related to the latest drivers `nvidia-319-updates`. Reverting back to `304` fixed my problems, although I call this rather a workaround than a fix, as I won't get many of the recent performance improvements of newer drivers.

Answer (score 5):

the only way to change brightness is to use this command

```
sudo su

echo 150 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

all other solution does not work at the moment.
this is not my work around. I don't remember where I found this but it works and hats off to the person who gave this workaround :)

Using Ubuntu 13.10 64Bit Wubi on Lenovo Z570

Comment: This does not work on my system.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using intel video card do:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Add the following in the empty file then log out and log in again or reboot. That should fix your problem.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection
```

Comment: This does not work. Can you please propose this workaround in the bug report that I list?

Comment: @lngo If you run this command, what comes as your video card?
`for i in /sys/class/backlight/*; do echo $i; cat $i/brightness; cat $i/actual_brightness; cat $i/max_brightness; done`

Comment: Never mind I see that you have an nvidia video card, this only works for intel cards

Comment: This fixes the issue for my Z570 on 16.10, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the NVidia and Intel are separate bugs as seen on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-319/+bug/1241745/comments/17. I filed a separate bug for Intel: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1255428.

For Intel, the solution given above does indeed work. An alternate is, you may just do in a terminal:

```
echo 150 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

i.e. avoiding the sudo su or whatever and merging the two steps into one.

Note that this solution involves the problem of piping the output of a command to a file requiring su permission for writing to. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr and https://stackoverflow.com/a/20234210/1503120.

I also wrote a simple PyQt4 GUI for this workaround. Please see the Intel LP bug for that.

Answer (score 0):

As an interim workaround I use:

xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.8

To list output devices, execute "xrandr" without any flags.